# laravel groupby with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

i have post with category

```
 $response=Post::groupBy('post_category','id')->get();
```

The above query will return all posts with category in the order of category.

Now i need to group all post inside category. Now i have one possible solution is i need to loop response and inside loop i have to check for category and create array.
Is there a option to make it in a query something like `groupconcat`.?

My question is: **Is it possible to create an array of category so key of an array is `category_name` and inside of category all post**?

**Updated**

Post table

```
id | post_name | post_description | category_name | etc..
```

Here category name is not using any other table since its predefined values like news, sports, cricket something like... When i am inserting news, sports, political in `categoryname`.

Comment: Can you please share your table schema?

Comment: @sunitiyadav.updated question

Comment: @vision you want something like a pivot table on category_name?

Comment: somethink similar as you said without pivot table.i just want to club baes on category .otherwise i have to loop it and create an array. similar to has many

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will return the key, value pair of post with unique category_name

```
$response = Post::get()->groupBy('category_name');
/*
    [
        'category_1' => [
            ['category_name' => 'category_1', 'post_name' => 'Chair'],
            ['category_name' => 'category_1', 'post_name' => 'Bookcase'],
        ],
        'category_2' => [
            ['category_name' => 'category_2', 'post_name' => 'Desk'],
        ],
    ]
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with a query, SQL group by will keep only one post for category so your query is incorrect. What you are looking for is:

```
$response = Post::get();
$response = $response->groupBy('post_category');
```

It will return a collection of arrays keyed by 'post_category' and containing all post from this category.

Comment: @aaron0207.thanks a lot.this is what  i was looking for.thanks a lot

Comment: Nice, you are welcome sir. If this worked you can check it as correct answer to help future readers. Maybe you should mark Praveen's answer since he was a bit faster

Comment: @aaron.i like your attutde for saying accepting answer of praveens.even i confused since you both helped me.thanks a lot once again.